# Find whole word for matching

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to get the regex pattern to find whole word if it matches a word\special character

```
text = Details of Test-3K9Y9Y1-My-Node1 give me
```

I want to get `Test-3K9Y9Y1-My-Node1` from the sentence.

I tried:

```
>>> match = re.findall('(?<=-)\w+', text)
>>> match
['3K9Y9Y1', 'My', 'Node1']
```

Comment: Your regex matches one or more word characters which are preceded by a `-`. Can you provide more details/examples of what exactly you would like it to match?

Comment: I want to match "-" and find the whole word , means `Test-3K9Y9Y1-My-Node1`

Comment: If I get it right, you would match any words that contain at least one time the character `-`, in any positions? Could you provide a list of examples that you would like to match?

Comment: You want to match any word that contains a `-` where the characters permitted in words are uppercase and lowercase letters and digits and `-`? If so, perhaps `[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*-[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the following regular expression:

```
>>match = re.findall('[^ ]*-[^ ]*', text)
```

And you could try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/CqFegl/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
text = 'Details of Test-3K9Y9Y1-My-Node1 give me'
s=text.split(' ')
for i in s:
    if '-' in i:
        print(i.split('-')
```

Comment: if want whole as single word use print(i)

Comment: Actually I am looking for regex pattern.

Comment: use match=re.findall('\w+[-]\w+',text)